# Is it okay to open specific app in order to register new account?

Tags: ios

Our company is developing iOS app. At some point user will need to login with account created in another service. If user doesn't have such account, we would like to open specific app which have register option and after successful registration get back to our app.

From Apple point of view - is it in accordance with their policies and doesn't have any impact on review process?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's completely okay since registration happens through your server I think you might not get into any trouble